# how to back press between several fragment

Tags: java, android

how to backPress button  between several fragment :

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements OnBackClickListener{


@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

}


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Override onBackPressed in the Activity and add all the Fragments to BackStack before committing:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    final int count = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
    if (count == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer .